# Convert DataRow to object

Tags: c#, .net

I've created generic List and populate with some objects. Then List I mentioned before converted into DataTable to use in DataGridView. Problem is when I want get Row from this grid I have DataRow. I wanted to convert this to my object againt but not sure how to do it. Maybe you could give some example?

Thanks

Comment: a bit of code would be helpful...

Answer (score 11):

Well, if you can't or won't use an "ORM" (object-relational mapper, like Linq-to-SQL or NHibernate - that's exactly what these tools do, and do quite well for you), you'll have to do this yourself.

Converting a DataRow into a domain object model is pretty boring code, really:

```
public Customer ConvertRowToCustomer(DataRow row)
{
   Customer result = new Customer();

   result.ID = row.Field<int>("ID");
   result.Name = row.Field<string>("CustomerName");
   ..... // and so on

   return result;
}
```

The biggest challenge here is making this rock-solid and handling (or avoiding) all possible errors (like a field being NULL etc.).

Another possibility would be to have a constructor on your domain model object type that would take a `DataRow` as parameter and construct a new object from it.

Marc

Comment: Thanks,
Can I use this(of course with some changes) when I have many types to convert to. For example one DataTable has records with Customer data and other records with addresses? Do I have to use reflection ?

Comment: You could of course use reflection to generalize this method for any type, and to even further improve the degraded performance resulting from reflection you could use Reflection.Emit to generate dynamic assemblies and then add some lazy loading to your collections and at the end of the day you will understand that people have already taught about these problems and invented ORM such as NHibernate , Entity Framework, ... and you will realize that you've put efforts into something that already exists and that you could use for free.

Comment: Maybe I should explain why I don't use EF and other ORMs. I get some array of objects from WS and then populate grid with these items. Only reason why I convert this array into DataTable is that I wanted to sort and found many examples that converting into DataTable is good way to provide this.

Comment: Sorting of in-memory arrays is done pretty easy with Linq-to-Objects.

Comment: Well, I mean I wanted give user chance to sort data in grid. When I populate gird with array I wasn't able to do this

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're using a class `MyObject`, defined as follows :

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

You could do something like that :

```
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;

...

List<MyObject> list = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                       select new MyObject
                       {
                            Foo = row.Field<string>("foo"),
                            Bar = row.Field<int>("bar")
                       }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put your objects into a BindingList<> rather than a List<>?  Then you can skip the converting to DataTable and back again exercise. You may need to implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* on your objects, but once they are inside a BindingList, changes in the datagrid will automatically be applied to your underlying objects.

Sorting can be handled by either sorting the list manually on column header click, or by inheriting from BindingList<> and implementing the sorting functionality inside it - then clicking on a header automatically sorts the list - no code required.

Answer (score 0):

Well nowadays it is easier using ORMs of course. But if still you're using the old fashion you can go with a pretty easy Extension Class to do the job for you using a little bit of reflection and generic methods and lambda as follows:

```
public static class MapperExtensionClass
{

        public static IEnumerable<MyClassType> ToMyClassTypeEnumerable(this DataTable table)
        {
            return table.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.ToMyClassType());
        }

        public static MyClassType ToMyClassType(this DataRow row)
        {            
            return row.ToObject<MyClassType>();
        }

        public static T ToObject<T>(this DataRow row) where T: new()
        {
            T obj = new T();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(property.Name))
                {
                    property.SetValue(obj, property.PropertyType.ToDefault(row[property.Name]));
                }
            }

            return obj;
        }


        public static object ToDefault(this Type type, object obj)
        {
            if (type == null)
                throw new Exception("Customized exception message");

            var method = typeof(MapperExtensionClass)
                .GetMethod("ToDefaultGeneric", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

            var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);

            return generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });            
        }

        public static T ToDefaultGeneric<T>(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return default(T); 
            }
            else
            {
                return (T)obj;
            }
        }
}
```

You should also remember GridView objects can bind a lot of data source types. So it is your decision from a design point about what you should go with.